# React-Bootstrap Modal - Error when unmounting from DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap modal component. I wish to unmount from the page but experience an error that I am unable to pinpoint even after debugging deep into the React source code.

I've figured out a way to unmount the component from the DOM without any errors but I would like to know the *why*...

The error i'm experiencing:

> Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.3.1`. If you're seeing this message, it probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At this time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time.warning
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined

Sample component that throws error when unmounting, notice the `closeModal` method towards the bottom

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let ReactBootstrapModal = React.createClass({   
   render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={true} onHide={closeModal}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Sample</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            Some body...
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    );   } });

var $$modalContainer = document.querySelector('#app-modal');

ReactDOM.render(<ReactBootstrapModal/>, $$modalContainer);

let closeModal = function(){
  try {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode($$modalContainer);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

A sample component that works without any errors when unmounting - the difference here is I wrap the `unmountComponentAtNode` in a `setTimeout` for 10 millisec and no error is thrown:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let ReactBootstrapModal = React.createClass({   
   render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={true} onHide={closeModal}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Sample</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            Some body...
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    );   } });

var $$modalContainer = document.querySelector('#app-modal');

ReactDOM.render(<ReactBootstrapModal/>, $$modalContainer);

let closeModal = function(){
  try {
    setTimeout(function(){ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode($$modalContainer)},10);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Comment: Why are you manually unmounting? That must be some very special edge case..

Comment: @azium What do you mean? Is there an automated process for mounting React?

Comment: Yes. The very first time you call render, the top level component mounts and recursively mounts all its children. Whenever render is called again because state has changed, or component receives new props, any component that is no longer part of children gets unmounted. I've been working with fairly complex React apps for a year now and have never seen anyone call `umountComponent`

Comment: edge case is when you use Portals for modals or something like this. I have the same issue. Thanks @CoryRobinson for providing the workaround 